# Crystal Reports Report Footer on Even Page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that has two report footers ('a' and 'b'). Report footer 'a' has to be a certain size, must be on an odd page, and must print on the bottom of the page. Report footer 'b' has to be on an even page. Typically this report is only 2 pages with report footer 'a' on the bottom of page 1 and report footer 'b' on the top of page 2.

However, sometimes the details of the report don't leave enough room for report footer 'a' so it goes to page 2 and since it must print on the bottom of the page, then pushes report footer 'b' to page 3. Ideally, what would happen is if report footer 'a' is on an even page, it should push itself to page 3 (leaving page 2 completely blank) and report footer 'b' would be on page 4.

I've opted to use report footers rather than page footers because the information in the report footers only comes after all of the details. So report footer 'a' should only appear once on the last odd page and report footer 'b' should appear once on the last even page.

I tried setting the "New Page Before" for report footer 'a' to:

```
    pagenumber mod 2 = 0
```

but that didn't work.

I think because report footer 'a' is already on a page by itself so it doesn't make a new page, but I could be wrong.

Any help at all would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I can see you done everything correct, but I had need more clarity in your formula.

Got the formula for `New page before` option and write below code.

```
If pagenumber mod 2 = 0 
then true
else false
```

let me know after trying this formula.

Comment: I don't see a change using this formula